# select box typeable and search the data in the database contents

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drupal-7

how to make a select box typeable, in the sense how can i type inside a select box , the value need not be in any of the options. The second part is that i need to search for this data in my entire database and retrieve the results. Is there any efficient way rather than this:

```
    SELECT * FROM db1 WHERE id = ".$myVAR." OR col1= ".$myVAR." OR col2 OR col3  = ".$myVAR."
    SELECT * FROM db2 WHERE id = ".$myVAR." OR col1= ".$myVAR." OR col2 OR col3  = ".$myVAR."
    SELECT * FROM db3 WHERE id = ".$myVAR." OR col1= ".$myVAR." OR col2 OR col3  = ".$myVAR."
```

Comment: Please check my answer for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Syamili V, Please check below solution for your problem :

There is a [good example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) of precisely this on the jQueryUI demo page for auto-complete functionality. It actually uses a select element from data.

You could easily modify this to use a remote data source (Your database data result).

Comment: Yes sure, Please kindly check the above link so you can have idea for the same.

Comment: i could see that only a single table data is being serached here, right?

Comment: You can fire query for multiple tables too & you can bind your result to remote data source as i mentioned earlier. Everything depend upon your dynamic data. Hope this answers helps you to resolve your problem. You can accept my answer if it really helps to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: okey,no problem.Hope this answers helps you to resolve your problem. You can accept my answer if it really helps to you. Thanks.

Comment: ` $.widget( "custom.custom_select",` iam getting an error as undefined. can u please help me what is the `custom ` here in http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox @PHP Weblineindia

Comment: Please put custom_select is your selectbox id. i.e <select id="custom_select">. Hope you can understand this.

Comment: it should be a class and not ID? "custom" = i dont know ....& the custom_select i added is my select box class name